# ViewPager in ListView items

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-viewpager, swipe

I implemented `ViewPager` in `ListView` items. In general works perfect, but have some issue. 
When I scroll `ListView` and then touch on screen (during scrolling list) in this case I can't scroll `ViewPager` in this item, `ListView` has focus. I should select it again for ability to swipe. `ListView` has returned `SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL` state, when I touch it during the scroll. At this moment I should focused on `ViewPager` for ability to swipe items.

Can I solve this issue without any scroll conflicts in `ListView` and `ViewPager`? I guess that it's imposible, but, decided to ask here.

Or, maybe you can advice me to use some other control to implementing swipe in `ListView` items. But scroll animation should be the same as on `ViewPager`.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your XML, you end up with needing to implement [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html). If the view you want to handle the event can handle it, then return true, if not false. Then the parent can handle it. You might also want to look at [ViewGroups](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html), particularly the onInterceptTouchEvent.